# How to get Iterable<Item> phones values in Flutter using the package contacts_services?

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't print or access the phone numbers in the contacts since it's `Iterable`. Instead of the phone number, it's showing `Instance of 'Item'` and couldn't find any solutions too. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Flutter Contacts Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, `contact.phones` returns a `List<Item>`.

`Item` is a class from the [package](https://github.com/lukasgit/flutter_contacts/blob/master/lib/contacts_service.dart) defined as follows:

```
class Item {
  Item({this.label, this.value});
}
```

Therefore, if you'd like to print out the values, you could use a source like the following:

```
contact.phones.forEach((phone) => print("${phone.label}: ${phone.value}"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `phones` member of the `Contact` class is a list, not a single item. You will need to iterate it with a loop.

Make sure you can find such things out yourself. Your IDE has a feature called "Show definition" or some similar translation. By default it's <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>, but your keyboard layout may vary. It will jump to the source where this type or member is defined and you can look for yourself what it is and how you want to use it.